# How to say "instructions for the/an exercise" in Japanese?

Tags: word-choice

How to say "instructions for the/an exercise" in Japanese?

I found the term 指示, [here](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=instruction), [here](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/instruction), and [here](https://www.ei-navi.jp/dictionary/content/instruction/), but also the terms 命令 and 説明書 in those links, which seem to me to be potential options.

In this picture of an exercise, what I refer to as "instructions for an exercise" is squared in red with a red arrow pointed to it. The original image before this personal modification comes from [here](https://www.liveworksheets.com/uz870280qq)

[image: Instructions for the exercise]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most common word for that is [設問{せつもん}](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E8%A8%AD%E5%95%8F/#jn-124833).

As the dictionary says, it can mean (the activity of) creating a problem/question, but also the problem/question itself.

To some extent, 設問 is similar to 質問, but 設問 is usually used to refer to questions/instructions in exercises or (paper) exams.

Comment: Thank you. So can we say これ質問の設問?

Comment: @starckman You need to use just one: この設問. Or, you could say この**問題**の設問. 質問 is usually not used for 'problems' in textbooks or exams.

Comment: And is it possible to have 問題の**質問**?

Comment: @starckman Yes, but 質問 is unusual in the context (though not totally impossible).